# Docker host networking - speicify network interface

Tags: docker, networking

I am trying to run a docker container using the `--network host` option on an embedded linux system. There are two eth interfaces, `eth0` and `eth1`. The `eth0` interface is used for ethernet to serial and should not be used for anything else.

Whenever I try running my container using the `--network host` option, docker tries to run it on the ip address of `eth0`. I need docker to instead run the container using the host ip address of `eth1`.

The only thing I have tried to get it this to work is to bring the `eth0` interface down. This won't work because I need both interfaces up. I need to make this work with host networking. Is there some way to specify the interface to use when I use `docker run`? If not is there some way to set a constraint in linux to use `eth1` for docker instead of `eth0`?

Comment: If you use `--network=host` then Docker doesn't try to run it on any particular host interface; your application is responsible for binding to whichever interface it uses.  You should very rarely need host networking; why are you using it here?  (With standard Docker networking, `docker run -p` can take a host IP address to bind to, so `-p 10.10.10.10:80:8888` forwards port 80 specifically on the interface with that IP address to container port 8888, but host networking disables this functionality.)

Comment: I was using host networking because I have two PC's connected via ethernet. It seemed like the easiest way to get the docker container able to communicate with the other PC. I am fairly new to docker. It's also on an embedded system and it seems the default bridge network driver isn't working correctly (iptables errors). Didn't want to mess around with getting iptables to work. 

But thanks for your tip about  the"application is responsible for binding to whichever interface it uses". I was able to edit the server code to use my desired interface. Cheers!